# Importing numpy array into R using rPython package

Tags: python, json, r, numpy

In pycharm I have code that works as intended. There is a function that when called returns a numpy array.

I'd like to get that array into RStudio's environment in say a dataframe or anything really as a starting point.

This is my simple code

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(rPython)
locTest <-"/home/cornelis/Downloads/M1302000139_1442697993.722772.raw"
x<-python.call("get_frames",locTest,256,256)
```

And here is the output. The numpy array displayed in RStudio's console is correct but it tells me it is not JSON serializable. I also realize that package rPython's [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/rPython.pdf) doesn't assign python.call to anything but I don't otherwise know how to assign the returned values of a Python function call to a variable in R (documentation is a bit thin though hopefully I'm just not looking in the right place)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: array([[[ 14.,  15.,  15., ...,   2.,   3.,   3.],
        [ 14.,  15.,  15., ...,   3.,   3.,   3.],
        [ 14.,  13.,  13., ...,   2.,   2.,   3.],
        ..., 
        [  2.,   2.,   2., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  2.,   2.,   3., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  3.,   4.,   3., ...,   1.,   1.,   2.]],

       [[ 11.,  13.,  13., ...,   3.,   3.,   3.],
        [ 11.,  11.,  12., ...,   3.,   3.,   3.],
        [ 11.,  11.,  10., ...,   2.,   3.,   4.],
        ..., 
        [  1.,   2.,   3., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   3.,   2., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  2.,   2.,   2., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.]],

       [[ 12.,  13.,  14., ...,   4.,   3.,   3.],
        [ 12.,  11.,  11., ...,   3.,   4.,   4.],
        [ 11.,  11.,   9., ...,   3.,   4.,   3.],
        ..., 
        [  1.,   2.,   2., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  2.,   2.,   2., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  2.,   2.,   3., ...,   2.,   1.,   1.]],

       ..., 
       [[ 74.,  77.,  78., ...,  88.,  89.,  89.],
        [ 77.,  78.,  76., ...,  89.,  89.,  88.],
        [ 79.,  78.,  77., ...,  89.,  87.,  88.],
        ..., 
        [ 39.,  38.,  34., ...,  56.,  56.,  53.],
        [ 38.,  39.,  35., ...,  55.,  56.,  55.],
        [ 36.,  38.,  36., ...,  55.,  56.,  58.]],

       [[ 81.,  79.,  79., ...,  93.,  91.,  92.],
        [ 79.,  78.,  78., ...,  91.,  93.,  91.],
        [ 78.,  78.,  78., ...,  89.,  90.,  88.],
        ..., 
        [ 39.,  37.,  35., ...,  59.,  57.,  55.],
        [ 37.,  35.,  36., ...,  59.,  59.,  57.],
        [ 38.,  38.,  37., ...,  56.,  60.,  61.]],

       [[ 79.,  79.,  79., ...,  89.,  90.,  91.],
        [ 77.,  78.,  78., ...,  89.,  89.,  88.],
        [ 77.,  77.,  76., ...,  88.,  86.,  86.],
        ..., 
        [ 40.,  36.,  33., ...,  59.,  58.,  59.],
        [ 36.,  35.,  33., ...,  58.,  58.,  57.],
        [ 35.,  36.,  36., ...,  59.,  57.,  58.]]], dtype=float32) is not JSON serializable
Error in python.get("_r_call_return") : Variable not found
```

The [following is the only related question I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602716/how-to-import-a-site-package-from-rjython/16709798#16709798)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up needing to change the python code such that the numpy array is converted to a list.

After messing around with a coworker and squinting at the documentation for a few more hours it turns out that I additionally needed to have the python.load before the python.call

the following works

```
> library(RJSONIO)
> library(rPython)
> python.load("/home/cornelis/PycharmProjects/TestProject/TestScript.py")
> firstFrame_raw<-python.call("get_frames","/home/cornelis/Downloads/M1302000139_1442697993.722772.raw",256,256)
> firstFrame_raw
...
[[2]][[46]]
  [1]   7   8   7   7   7   5   7   6   6   6   5   5   5   5   5   4   6   5   6   5   4   4   4   4
 [25]   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   3   3   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   0   1
 [49]   2   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   3   3   3   4   4   3   4   4   6   1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a new R package called "reticulate", which seems more capable than rPython.

https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/calling_python.html

In particular, the documentation says "R matrices and arrays are converted automatically to and from NumPy arrays," and the function calls look really straightforward.